# VB Script InputBox query

Tags: vbscript, inputbox

Im just trying to make a simple input script something like this where "FJobName" is the variable I want to insert in raiseevent string "FJobName". Any ideas, what I got aint workin?

```
Dim FJobName, objShell
FJobName=InputBox ("JobName","ACT Create Job")
result=Msgbox(FJobName ,vbYesNo)
If result = vbYes Then
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell")
objShell.run "raiseevent ACTCreateJob_r3 FJobName -host 194.128.255.22 -port 61235"
Else
End if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate FJobName with the command string. I.e. your script should look like this:

```
Dim FJobName, objShell
FJobName=InputBox("JobName","ACT Create Job") 
result=Msgbox(FJobName ,vbYesNo) 
If result = vbYes Then 
   Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell") 
   objShell.run "raiseevent ACTCreateJob_r3 " & FJobName & " -host 194.128.255.22 -port 61235" 
End if
```